# Can i delete multiple emails using RPA Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I'm trying to do a task of Gmail to delete the particular messages in Automation Anywhere using Object Cloning and looping, looping is being done only for the first message even after giving the $counter$ in the path(after capturing) where it has to select the multiple emails in Gmail inbox. please have a look at the code in the attached screenshot. Any inputs are appreciated Thank You!

```
1.open browser
2.object cloning:Get Property 'HTML Inner Text'of static text""from windows 'Inbox*';Assign to variable"$Prompt-Assignment",Source:Window;play-Type:object
3.Start loop"$Prompt-Assignment$"Times
4.object cloning:Get Property 'HTML Inner Text' of static text"Indeed" from windows 'Inbox*';Assign to variable "$Vsubject",Source:Window;play-Type:object
5.if $Vsubject$ EqualTo(=)"Indeed" Then
6.object cloning:click on pane windows 'Inbox*';Click type:Click;Source:Window;play-Type:object
```

Comment: missing screenshot

Comment: Please post the code as text so that we can edit and test it

Comment: `1.open browser
2.object cloning:Get Property 'HTML Inner Text'of static text""from windows 'Inbox*';Assign to variable"$Prompt-Assignment",Source:Window;play-Type:object
3.Start loop"$Prompt-Assignment$"Times
4.object cloning:Get Property 'HTML Inner Text' of static text"Indeed" from windows 'Inbox*';Assign to variable "$Vsubject",Source:Window;play-Type:object
5.if $Vsubject$ EqualTo(=)"Indeed" Then
6.object cloning:click on pane windows 'Inbox*';Click type:Click;Source:Window;play-Type:object
`  @SimonCrane(I have added the code, please have a look.)

Comment: Use Email Automation Command to delete message instead of the Object Cloning.

Comment: You can partially use my guide here[https://rpaknowledge.com/automation-anywhere-send-email-command/] to setup smtp to gmail. Instead of sending an email, use the command to get all emails. There's an option to delete them inside the command itself.

Comment: Show us the domXpath mentioned in both object cloning inside the loop. also is your loop able to select all mails which are supposed to be deleted?

Comment: Looping is being done, but it's being done for the only one message. For example, I need to loop for 10 times where it needs to select 10 multiple messages with the name "Indeed" which I mentioned in the code, but it is selecting only one checkbox for 10 times. @TanmayGawankar

Comment: Please check the path and DOMXPath of object cloning given before If-condition in the loop                                                                                                              'Path : 19|3|1|2|1|2|1|1|1|1|2|1|1|1|1|6|1|1|3|1|1|2|$Counter$|5|2|1|1
DOMXPath : /html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[5]/div[2]/span[1]/span[1]' @TanmayGawankar

Answer (score 1):

Where you are capturing the value for your prompt-assignment will be first question.

If you have to delete certain emails which contains 'xxxxx' subject, then i would say

1. Clone the search text box in Gmail and set the text to 'Subject:xxxx'
2. Then clone the Search push button 
   Then Gmail will give filter list, please check the list that it generated to you, if that is appropriate and exact.
3. You can clone the comment select all check-box which selects all this resulted emails
4. Use Object cloning command to delete them.

Hope this helps , else please mention the condition that you are using to make decision to select the emails that needs to be deleted .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you had any specific reason to use Object cloning for deleting emails which Include "Indeed".

My suggestion would be to try the below code. There would be no interaction with the UI, everything will be done in the backend. You just need to configure your gmail account when using the loop command.

```
1   Start Loop "Each  message on server: mail.myisp.com, User Name: test@gmail.com,  ServerType: IMAP, Message Format: HTML"
2        If $Email Subject$ Includes "Indeed" Then  
3             Delete Message
4        End If
5   End Loop
```